# Confirm before replacing an existing file in the folder using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, upload, sweetalert

I have an upload form and I would like to show a confirmation message

> "The destination already contains the same file. Do you want to
>   replace it? - (Show two buttons, Replace & Cancel )"

It should popup before uploading the file to the destination folder.

The logic is given below

```
if (CSV exists){
        if(replace file== yes) {
            upload file
        }else{
            do nothing.
        }
}else{
    upload file
}
```

how can I do the same with PHP ? 
NB: I am using sweet alert jquery for customized popup messages.. Sample code is given below

```
                    <script>
                        $().ready(function () {
                        /*swal*/
                        swal({
                            title: "File already exists!",
                            text: "CSV file is already existing in the folder, do you want to replace it?",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                            confirmButtonText: "Replace",
                            closeOnConfirm: false,
                            closeOnCancel: true
                        },
                        function(isConfirm){
                            if (!isConfirm)return;
                            if (isConfirm == true) {

                            }
                        });//is confirm function
                        /*swal*/
                        });//document ready 
                    </script>
```

my code is not complete because, the file has already been replace even before I choose the replace option or cancel option. any idea how to solve this.?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do an AJAX request to a PHP file which can return the message if the file exists or not. In PHP your logic will be:

```
if( file_exists($path_to_csv) ){
    if( $replace === TRUE ) {
        file_put_contents($path_to_csv, $data);
        $ret = json_encode(['type'=> 'warning', 'text' =>'File existed and was replaced.']);
    } else {
      $ret = json_encode(['type'=> 'error', 'text' => 'File already exists and will not be replaced.']);
    } 
} else {
    file_put_contents($path_to_csv, $data);
    $ret = json_encode(['type'=> 'message', 'text' => 'File created']);
}

echo $ret;
```